# Accessing Local Host

Tags: node.js, localhost

I am completing NodeSchool's stream-adventure tutorial. One of the exercises, called WebSockets, has the following instructions:

"In this adventure, write some browser code that uses the websocket-stream module
to print the string 'hello\n'.

Your solution file will be compiled with browserify and the verify script will
prompt you to open `http://localhost:8099` in a browser to verify your solution."

Here was my passing solution:

```
var ws = require("websocket-stream");
var stream = ws("ws://localhost:8099");

stream.write("hello\n");
```

The instructions now say:

"Open http://localhost:8099 to run your code!"

When I try to do this in Chrome, the browser says "This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect. What can I do?

Comment: You might want to check your hosts file to ensure that localhost actually points to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @AdamF How do I check this?

Comment: Depends on your OS. If you use mac or linux, your host file is at `/etc/hosts`, on windows it's at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`